# TcpClient - receive multiple messages from client on callback

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

I am trying to create a TCP Listener, who receives the clients, keeps them open and when they send a data call a Callback Method.
I can't seem to find out how to add the callback and how to keep the client open.

My current Code looks like this:

```
 protected void Listener()
    {
        TcpListener __Listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, Port);
        __Listener.Start();
        long _TicketNo = 0;

        while (IsRunning)
        {
            client = __Listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            _TicketNo++;

            RFIDReaderCommunication work = new RFIDReaderCommunication(client);
            Trigger(work.process());

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

The work.process() simply reads the bytes from the network stream.

but this only receives data once from the Client.
Can anybody give me a hint how to receive data multiple times from this single connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `client = __Listener.AcceptTcpClient();` inside your loop. This means as soon as the loop comes back around to the top, you're blocking to wait for the next incoming connection, and then overwriting your `client` variable.

For a start, move this line above the loop.